# Customized week of year (5 or more days this year)

Tags: mysql, date

There are modes in MySQL week() function, which could define

```
"Week 1 is the first week with 4 or more days this year".
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

However, I met a special client, they have defined that

```
"Week 1 is the first week with 5 or more days this year".
```

Is there any way to set this rule, or any other workaround to mitigate this?

Example:

[image]
According to the client's rule, this week belongs to year 2015, because there are 5 days in 2015. But in MySQL week(), mode can only be set if there are more than 4 days in this year, or first Sunday/Monday.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Example added. Thanks for your reminding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got your requirement right, but I would use the function with the mode that matches your requirements best of all (Sun vs Mon as start day, 0 or 1 start week number) and would call `WEEK()` function with the same parameters for the previous day. If it belongs to the same week number, then there are 5 days. Otherwise, return incremented value (next week).

So assume you need to find the first week with 5 days for the given date `date`.

`IF(WEEK(date, 1) = WEEK(DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY),1), WEEK(date,1), WEEK(date,1) + 1)`